# Send AES Key and IV to client

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes

Is it safe to send a mobile client an AES Key and IV from the server to use for encrypting sensitive data? The key and IV would be sent using TLS. This key would be used for encrypting data from end to end.

**Update**:

My requirements have actually changed, so I don't need to do this, but the solution I came up with was actually to have the client send a public key to the server over tls. Then the server could encrypt the keys with that public key and send them back to the client.

Answer (score 3):

It would be as secure as any data in TLS. It also depends on how much your client trusts this TLS, which may not have two sided authentication.

But basically sending the key this way doesn't *add* much to using TLS. If TLS is insecure then the AES key is insecure. If it isn't then the AES key is secure...but TLS was already secure. There might be a slight advantage if you'd use a ciphersuite that provides forward security (DHE_ or ECDHE_).

But mostly, if you send anything, you'd send a *public key* such as a PGP key. The person on the other hand still has to trust the sender of course (i.e. by validating the fingerprint) but if the TLS connection is insecure then leaking the public key would at least not break anything encrypted using it.

Comment: The problem with the client sending everything using a public key is that the decryption is too slow for a high volume server.

Comment: Decryption is a whole lot faster with Elliptic Curves ( e.g. using ECIES). Note that you shouldn't see this answer as a full protocol design - just hints in the right direction.

Comment: And of course hybrid cryptography (encrypt random AES data key with public key, use that to encrypt the bytes, reverse at receiver).